# PROCEDURE SELECT IN ORACLE

Tags: oracle

I'm new to Oracle--can somebody help me with this procedure?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE JAKARTA
as
BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM
karyawan
WHERE
alamat = 'Jakarta';
COMMIT;
END jakarta; 
/
```

When I run this I get the following

> Warning : Procedure created with complication errors.

Please help...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a stored procedure to display the information of employees from a particular department in PL/SQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183452/how-to-write-a-stored-procedure-to-display-the-information-of-employees-from-a-p)

Comment: Are you sure you got that error message right?

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE and thanks for participating. In order to provide you with an answer, we would require additional information. E.g. what version of Oracle are you using? (10g, 11g, 12c, 18c)  What tool are you using to create the procedure? Is the error message correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to select some data inside a procedure then it needs to go into something.  You have not shown us the complete error message but I suspect it is

```
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

Revise your code to provide a target of the same type as the data selected. I removed the commit as is not necessary unless you UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE something after changing it. Something like

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE JAKARTA
    as
    --declare a type with all the same columns as the karyawan table
        TYPE karyawanType IS RECORD (
            id karyawan.id%type,
            alamat karyawan.alamat%type,
        );
    --declare a record of the type you created
    v_record karyawanType;

    BEGIN
    SELECT *
    INTO v_record
    FROM
    karyawan
    WHERE
    alamat = 'Jakarta';

    END jakarta; 
    /
```

Comment: Please change `v_record` to be data type `karyawan%rowtype`.  Thanks. (and drop the `karyawnType`.